# Hide Labe at specific page on a scrollView swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have an UIScrollView and an UILabel on a ViewController. If the user arrives at the last page of the scrollView, the Label should be hidden. How can I do that? Here is my unfinished code:

```
    swipeLabel.center.x = self.view.frame.width + 30

    self.comingSoonLabel.isHidden = false

    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
    let scrollviewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.height
    let scrollviewWidth = self.scrollView.frame.width

    let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollviewWidth, height: scrollviewHeight))
    let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollviewWidth, y: 0, width: scrollviewWidth, height: scrollviewHeight))
    let feedbackView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollviewWidth*4, y: 0, width: scrollviewWidth, height: scrollviewHeight))

    imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "preview1")
    imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "preview2")

    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(feedbackView)

    self.addChildFeedBack(feedbackView: feedbackView)

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.frame.width * 3, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
    self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

}

func addChildFeedBack(feedbackView: UIView){
    let contestStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "feedback", bundle: nil)
    let testVC = contestStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeedbackViewController") as! FeedbackViewController
    testVC.view.frame = feedbackView.bounds
    feedbackView.addSubview(testVC.view)
    self.addChildViewController(testVC)
    testVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    self.comingSoonLabel.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get pageNumber using scrollview's delegate method.

**Note -You need to assign delegate of scrollview and conform that delegate also.**

```
scrollview.delegate = self //assign

class testClass: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate // conform
```

**Delegate**

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
         if pageNumber == 3{
          // hide your label here 
         }
        // do you logic related to last page
    }
```

Comment: I don't realy understand. How can access the last page in the `func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`?

Comment: it not last number you need to add logic for that. it is only current page number while your scrolling stopped .

Comment: So then I only need that function and I can add `self.comingSoonLabel.isHidden = true` or do I need additional stuff?

Comment: Now, the Label is hidden after the first touch/scroll. I need this action at the last page. But I also need, that the Label is shown when I'll go back to the previous page.

Comment: It does not yet work well. When I scroll, the Label disappear for 1sec but after that, it is not hidden again

Comment: Maybe the mistake is at the begin, how should `scrollView.delegate = self` looks like?